# How to start slrn and use the jnewsrc file?

Tags: command-line, server, configuration, email, email-client

I'm not understanding how to start slrn, particularly with the jnewsrc versus newsrc files:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ slrn
slrn 1.0.3

Loading /usr/share/slrn/slang/slrn.sl
Reading startup file /etc/news/slrn.rc.
Using newsrc file /home/nicholas/.jnewsrc for server mordor.saundersconsulting.tech.slrn fatal error:

Unable to open /home/nicholas/.jnewsrc.
If you want to create /home/nicholas/.jnewsrc, add command line options:
   -f /home/nicholas/.jnewsrc --create

nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ slrn -f /home/nicholas/.jnewsrc --create
slrn 1.0.3

Loading /usr/share/slrn/slang/slrn.sl
Reading startup file /etc/news/slrn.rc.
Using newsrc file /home/nicholas/.jnewsrc for server mordor.saundersconsulting.tech.
Connecting to host mordor.saundersconsulting.tech ...
Unable to make connection. Giving up.

Run-Time Error
slrn fatal error:
Failed to initialize server.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ls .jnewsrc
ls: cannot access '.jnewsrc': No such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ pwd
/home/nicholas
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Currently using Pan for NNTP with news.eternal-september.org as the server.

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

(There are no tags for slrn, pan, nntp or usenet?)

Comment: had the NNTPSERVER env variable in .bashrc set to my FQDN rather than the target news server.